# AZ CLI command to Configure customer-managed keys for encrypting Azure Service Bus data at rest throws error with Keyvault values

Tags: azure, encryption, azureservicebus

I am encountering error when trying to configure customer-managed keys for encrypting Azure Service Bus data at rest using Azure CLI. It complains

> All KeyVaultProperties must be specified as part of the Encryption object

Az cli cmd:

```
az servicebus namespace update --name <PremserivcebusName>  --set encryption.keyName='<Keyvault.KeyName'  encryption.keyVaultUri='<Keyvault.KeyUri>' encryption.keySource='Microsoft.KeyVault'  -g <resource-groupName> --debug
```

Error message

[image]

debug  message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to configure customer-managed keys for encrypting  Azure Service Bus data at rest using `az servicebus Namespace Update` [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/namespace?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-namespace-update) it is failing with the below error even if we pass the all properties of key vault as part of encryption object.

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can use the Service Bus **Namespace Create or Update** [REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/preview/namespaces/create-or-update) to configure customer-managed keys for encrypting  Azure Service Bus data at rest.

**REST API:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespaceName}?api-version=2021-06-01-preview
```

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine.

- In our local environment , we have created a premium service bus (enable system identity), Premium key vault(enabling purge & soft delete).
- We have used the above rest api to configure customer-managed keys for encrypting  Azure Service Bus data.

**Here is the Sample Request & Request body that we have used:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RgName>/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/<SBNamespaceName>?api-version=2021-06-01-preview
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
   "location":"<LocationOfSB>",
   "sku":{
      "name":"Premium",
      "tier":"Premium"
   },
   "identity":{
      "type":"SystemAssigned"
   },
   "properties":{
      "encryption":{
         "keySource":"Microsoft.KeyVault",
         "keyVaultProperties":[
            {
               "keyName":"<KeyName>",
               "keyVaultUri":"<KeyvaultUri>",
               "keyVersion":"<KeyVersionId>"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]